# Referring to a dynamic value in a dropdown command in XML

Tags: xml

I'd like to create a marker on a list of items that a referenced with a unique number through a dropdown list via `XML`.

Instead of listing these can I create a reference to a variable name from a single dropdown command?

```
<dropdown command="marker(&quot;item&quot,1)">Mark Item 1</dropdown>
<dropdown command="marker(&quot;item&quot,2)">Mark Item 2</dropdown>
<dropdown command="marker(&quot;item&quot,3)">Mark Item 3</dropdown>
<dropdown command="marker(&quot;item&quot,4)">Mark Item 4</dropdown>
<etc....>


%a = ItemNo
<dropdown command="marker(&quot;item&quot,%a)">Mark Item | %a</dropdown>
```